Identification: story about teens frustrated with school dress-codes
I've searched for the book several times to no avail. I read this book in the 90s, it may have been set in the 80s or 90s, but it was about a group of teenage, maybe highschool children who were frustrated with their school's dress code.
In particular, the girls were able to wear skirts, but the boys always had to wear pants.
So a group of teenage boys banded together (I think they may have had help from some girl friends) and started wearing skirts to school during a particularly hot year.

 As a result of their efforts, the teens were able to get the school administration to change the policy so that they could wear shorts when the weather was warmer, maybe above 80F?

I remember that the book cover had the boys wearing a variety of skirts on it.

Was this a book, or was it a news story? If it was a book, it's going to be hard to find thanks to modern protests against dress codes.

Agree. It’s a common silly season story in the UK. Mist reoccur every 2—3 years.

It was an actual book, unfortunately for the above reasons it's been ... "fun" to try and find. I thought revenge may have been in the title but that just got me revenge of the nerds (:

@WayneWerner On a whim, is it this?

@JBH AHHHH! That's exactly it! Or to be more precise the 1990 cover is it!

@WayneWerner That's a much better cover.

The Obnoxious Jerks by Stephen Manes
Found via Abe Books. However, OP remembers (and located) the cover, below, from the 1990 paperback.
Click for larger image.
Synopsis:
Who are the Obnoxious Jerks?
A: The weirdest band of total misfits ever seen at any known high school in the free world.
B: Amateur comedians whose routines include kazoos, used chewing gum, and gooey lemon meringue pies.
C: Members of a club whose Official Ice Cream Flavor is Nuts to You.
D: A disorganized organization whose exploits are required reading for anybody with a sense of humor.
All of the above--and more . . .
There are jerks in every high school. The Obnoxious Jerks are found only at Ullman Griswold Memorial High (or, as they prefer to call it, UGH). They specialize in pranks (better known as "jerk-outs") designed to show how ridiculous some school rules can be. Which means the detention hall sometimes becomes the Jerks' unofficial meeting room.
Then something happens to shake up Jerkdom: A girl known as "Iceberg" Freeze asks to join the all-male club-that's-not-a-club. It's not long before she finds herself at the center of the greatest jerk-out ever--one that involves picket signs, mass demonstrations, and guys wearing skirts.
What's acceptable behavior? What's worth fighting for? The Obnoxious Jerks twist, bend, and break the rules to find out. And in the process learn a lot about questioning not only the outside world, but also themselves.
